# Zed Notation in LyX

Tags: latex, specifications, lyx, z-notation

Is it possible to create Zed Notation schemes in LyX? How can it be done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solved it:

I installed the zed-csp style package through MikTeX.
Then, in LyX I went to `Document->Settings->Latex Preamble` and added

```
\usepackage{zed-csp}
```

then, to enter Zed schemes, symbols, etc., I used [this reference](http://fmt.cs.utwente.nl/courses/fmse/software/refcard.pdf)

It is entered through ERT (Evil Red Text) i.e., TeX code (Ctrl+L).
Zed segments in the code should be surrounded with a

```
\begin{zed}
...
\end{zed}
```

except schemes and such constructs that have a `\begin{..}` and `\end{..}`.

Answer (score 3):

If you can use LaTeX packages in LyX then you could try [zed-csp](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/zed-csp/).  How you install LaTeX packages for LyX I do not know.